# Tool for xml (.locale) file automatic translation - TAOBAO CHAT TRANSLATION IN ENGLISH

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, chat, translation

EDIT: 
Chat program name ALICHAT, ALIWANGWANG (taobao chat software)

I have a chat program installed on microsoft environment that uses a .locale file for the language customization.
it is structured like an xml file.
This is the file: http://www.tr3ma.com/apps/translatorTest/chs.locale_original

This is how it is structured:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LocaleDetails>
   <Strings>
    <String id="common.yes">是</String>
    <String id="common.no">否</String>
    <String id="common.remind">提示</String>
    <String id="common.ok">确定</String>
    <String id="common.edit">编辑</String>
    <String id="common.save">保存</String>
    <String id="common.cancel">取消</String>
      .....
```

Do you know if this file is a standard file for a microsoft development environment like the strings resource file for the android apps?
i found that for android apps there is a tool to translate the resources in any language. Is it there an equivalent for these .locale file ?
Which is the development environment they come from?

**The main question is: which tool to use to translate such big files?**

Fundamentally the problem is that this software is provided only in chinese language.

notes:

exe name: AliIM.exe

exe FILE PATH: C:\Program Files\AliWangWang

chs.locale FILE PATH: C:\Program Files\AliWangWang\8.00.08C\languages

Here you can download the program directly from the supplier: http://www.taobao.com/wangwang/

I found that the file chs.locale is used if you selected simplified chinese as language, otherwise the file cht.locale is used if you selected the traditional chinese language.

I started translating the file by hands and it have effect on the resulting language of the chat program but it is a really hard work since the file is enormous and it can not be translated automatically. before to post solutions try it by yourself cause i tried a lot of tools without success.

Comment: Essentially, are you asking whether there is a tool that natively processes the file format you are showing? If so, please change your question title to say more clearly (as it stands, you might as well be asking for someone else to translate that file; the focus of your question does not get clear in the title). However, it is possible you will get redirected to some other site on the StackExchange network as this question may not be a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: could i move it where it is more appropriated? Yes i'm asking for a tool that translates it automatically. It is not possible to translate it manually. It's a 100KB file, if you download it you will understand it. p.s.:I edited the title and the content.

Comment: *Maybe* [this new beta site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is more appropriate.

Comment: few days ago i read here a comment but now i can't see it. the comment stated that the tool no more works. i tried it again and i found it is still correctly working. regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while waiting your help i started creating a tool for  the automatic translation of  xml files.
The tool is written in vb.net, it loads the file, let's you choose for the language to translate from and to. It parses the xml file searching for the desired tags and translates the strings to the desired language, finally it recreates the file and saves it in the same folder with a different name.
Actually it is working even if some words are not translated.
The traditional chinese file translated to english, ready to be replaced to the original file is http://www.tr3ma.com/apps/translatorTest/chs.locale
consider that i used the original file relative to the chat version 8.00.08C. if you have different version of the chat, or you need to translate the .locale file of another application, **OR GENERALLY IF YOU NEED TO TRANSLATE A XML FILE**, you need to use the tool to retranslate your file.

As i already told it is not perfect. You can try it by yourself, you can download the tool  from http://www.tr3ma.com/apps/translatorTest/translator.zip

If your xml file is different you can also change the tags to search for in the 3 fields.

it's also slow in the translation.

hope it can help someone in my situation.
Here a screenshot:
[image]

Ask if it's not clear, or if you are tring to use it and you find difficulties.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for - doesn't work in wine though (Linux) OpenFileDialog1.. can't browse the dir tree

Comment: and when i keyed in Z:\root\chs.locale and selected cn-Simplified and en, and clicked Translate, it exited silently.

Comment: I tried Google Translate, but the 'file translate' thing doesn't work. Pasting bits of the file <500 lines works but it's way too slow. How are you doing the translate?

Comment: i never tried on wine. please, use it on windows, you just need to do it once, i don't plan to develop it for linux. i know the google translate limit. I extract from the xml file the single sentences to translate, then i ask the translation to google, then i replace the sentence in the xml file. please upload your chs.locale file and i will try to solve the bug. give me your email if you want sources in vb.net

Comment: few days ago i read here a comment but now i can't see it. the comment stated that the tool no more works. i tried it again and i found it is still correctly working. regards.

Comment: I tried to translate an xml language file with similar format for a Chinese software called QQ; the original file is in Simplified Chinese. I could load file and choose Source and Dest language, and started translatin but it later stopped after several minutes while it was processing characters and it displayed an error message saying: "Error during Translation, Retry?".  some items are as follows: <String id="Discuss_ModifyMemNameFail">
    修改我的名片失败。
  </String>
  <String id="Discuss_ViewInfo">
    查看资料
  </String>

Comment: Upload your file somewhere, I will try it

Answer (score 3):

here are new way:

1. download alibaba trademanager (taobao included)
2. go to `C:\Program Files(x86)\TradeManager\languages`
3. backup `english.***` `and chs.***`
4. delete `chs.***` and rename `english.***` to `chs.***`

result aliwangwang in english :D

[image: taobao english]

Comment: Great tip! Just tried this and it works. However you should not delete the english files, instead copy `english.***` to `chs.***`, otherwise the main interface will lose its language references.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gaucho and @uingtea
I've written python script to translate chs.locale.

0- Exit AliWangWang

1- go to C:\Program Files(x86)\TradeManager\languages

2- backup chs.locale to chs.locale_backup

3- delete chs.dat

4- run "python translateUI.py" (beside chs.locale)

5- repeat 4th step if needed (each time google translate limit it, wait(change IP !!) and run again! ) each time we run translateUI.py, it will ignore former translated ans start from last item

*** It would be easy if you run on linux. Maybe it will need some libraries

*** provided chs.locale is a translated file for version 9.12.07C

[ProjectLink](https://github.com/sdRezaHosseini/aliWangWangTranslation)